# translate from SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, plsql, triggers

I was hoping one of you Oracle experts would be able to give me a hand with this. I have the following SQL Server script, but I need to rewrite it for Oracle:

```
USE mydb
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE trigger mydb . [CONNECTERTRIGGER] on mydb . [DtreeNotify]
FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN

IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
  RETURN

SET IDENTITY_INSERT mydb.DTreeNotify2 ON

INSERT INTO mydb.DTreeNotify2 
   (NID,NType,DataID,VersionNum,OwnerID,SubType)
SELECT inserted.NID, 
       inserted.NType, 
       inserted.DataID,
       inserted.VersionNum,
       mydb.Dtree.OwnerID, 
       livelink.DTree.SubType
  FROM inserted, livelink.DTree
 WHERE inserted.DataID = livelink.DTree.DataID;

END
```

I think @@rowcount becomes sql%rowcount, but I'm struggling with the identity_insert bit. 
I don't think anything else should change. Opinions?

Comment: Can you reformat please. This hurts my eyes.  Note the "code" button.

Comment: @Bill: TSQL is good for that, even when it's formatted =)

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about the IDENTITY_INSERT bit, the way it is done in Oracle is so much different that there is no need for such an option anyway. Look for "SEQUENCE" to learn more about that.

Here we go:

```
CREATE trigger "CONNECTERTRIGGER"
  AFTER INSERT on "DtreeNotify"
  FOR EACH ROW
begin
  insert into DTreeNotify2 (NID,NType,DataID,VersionNum,OwnerID,SubType)
    select :new.NID, :new.NType, :new.DataID, :new.VersionNum,
           Dtree.OwnerID, livelink.DTree.SubType
      from livelink.DTree
      where :new.DataID=livelink.DTree.DataID;
end;
```

Comments: I assume Dtree.OwnerID is a package variable you can read directly.
As you can see, there is a `:new` record, which contains one inserted record (this trigger is called for each record that gets inserted).

Edit: changed the BEFORE trigger to an AFTER trigger

Comment: Followup from an Oracle novice. Why should this be a BEFORE INSERT and not an AFTER INSERT trigger?

Comment: Bill: no special reason, probably doesn't matter

Comment: do I always have to put a semicolon after an END?

Comment: After triggers are faster. Here's what the manual says:

Note: AFTER row triggers are slightly more efﬁcient than BEFORE
row triggers. With BEFORE row triggers, affected data blocks must
be read (logical read, not physical read) once for the trigger and
then again for the triggering statement.
Alternatively, with AFTER row triggers, the data blocks must be
read only once for both the triggering statement and the trigger.

Comment: so I make it an after trigger, then

Comment: Another reason to use after-insert is if there are any other before-insert triggers that could alter the data that is ultimately inserted

Comment: Yes, like one getting a unique ID from a sequence, or filling timestamp fields.